# docker keep restarting until file is created in a mounted volume

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, inotify

I am trying to create a script that would restart itself, a micro service (in my case its `node-red`).

Here is my docker compose file:

```
docker-compose.yml
```

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  wifi-connect:
    build: ./wifi-connect
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true

  google-iot:
    build: ./google-iot
    volumes:
      - 'app-data:/data'
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - "wifi-connect"
    ports:
      - "8883:8883"

  node-red:
    build: ./node-red/node-red
    volumes:
      - 'app-data:/data'
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - "google-iot"

volumes:
  app-data:
```

I am using [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) in order to check if the previous container.

Here is an extract from the Dockerfile of the node-red microservice.

```
RUN chmod +x ./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh

# server.js will run when container starts up on the device
CMD ["bash", "/usr/src/app/start.sh", "bash", "/usr/src/app/wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh google-iot:8883 -- echo Google IoT Service is up and running"]
```

I have seen the `inotify`.

Basically all I want is to restart the container `node-red` after a file has been created within the `app-data` volume which is mounted to the `node-red` container as well under `/data` folder path, the file path for e.g. would be: `/data/myfile.txt`.

Please note that this file gets generated automatically to the `google-iot` micro service but `node-red` container needs that file and pretty often is the case that the `node-red` container starts and `/data/myfile.txt` file is not present.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? Your requirement is not clear. Are you trying to debug why the container starts when the file is not there? (race condition) or are you trying to find an alternate way to continuously restart a container until you see the file? Or both?

Comment: @zer0: trying to find an alternate way to continuously restart a container until you see the file

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to delay one container's startup until another has produced the file you're looking for, or exit if it's not available.

You can write that logic into a shell script fairly straightforwardly.  For example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Wait for the server to be available
./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh google-iot:8883
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo 'google-iot container did not become available' >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Wait for the file to be present
seconds=30
while [ $seconds -gt 0 ]; do
  if [ -f /data/myfile.txt ]; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 1
  seconds=$(($seconds-1))
done
if [ $seconds -eq 0 ]; then
  echo '/data/myfile.txt was not created' >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Run the command passed to us as arguments
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, make this script be the `ENTRYPOINT`.  You must use JSON-array syntax in the `ENTRYPOINT` line.  Your `CMD` can use any valid syntax.  Note that we're running the `wait-for-it` script in the entrypoint wrapper, so you don't need to include that in the `CMD`.  (And since the script is executable and begins with a "shebang" line `#!/bin/sh`, we do not need to explicitly name an interpreter to run it.)

```bash
# Dockerfile
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/src/app/start.sh"]
```

The entrypoint wrapper has two checks, first that the `google-iot` container eventually accepts TCP connections on port 8883 and a second that the file is created.  If either of these cases fails the script `exit 1` before it runs the `CMD`.  This will cause the container as a whole to exit with that status code (a `restart: on-failure` will still restart it).

I also might consider whether some other approach to get the file might work, like using `curl` to make an HTTP request to the other container.  There are several practical issues with sharing Docker volumes (particularly around ownership, but also if an old copy of the file is still around from a previous run) and sharing files works especially badly in a clustered environment like Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue with the race condition by using the `long-syntax` of `depends_on` where you can specify a health check. This will guarantee that your file is present when your `node-red` service runs.

```
  node-red:
    build: ./node-red/node-red
    volumes:
      - 'app-data:/data'
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      google-iot:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Then you can define a `health-check` (see docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck)) to see if your file is present in the volume. You can add the following to the service description for `google-iot` service:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "cat", "/data/myfile.txt"]
  interval: 1m30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 40s
```

Feel free to tune the duration values as needed.

Does this fix your problem?